# How to input text into form during React/Jest/Enzyme Shallow Rendering testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following form:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } className="form-login">
    <ul>
        <li className="rel">
            <div className="icon-user-circle-o"></div>
            <input type="text" id="input-auth-username" placeholder="username" />
        </li>
        <li className="rel">
            <div className="icon-lock"></div>
            <input type="password" id="input-auth-password" placeholder="password" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <button className="btn-green" type="submit">Login</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

#### My current test

The first test passes, it's the 2nd test I'm unable to write at the moment.

```
describe('User Login', () => {
    it('should fail if no credentials are provided', () => {
        const fakeEvent = { preventDefault: () => '' };
        expect(loginComponent.find('.form-login').length).toBe(1);
        loginComponent.find('.form-login').simulate('submit', fakeEvent);
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
        // console.log(loginComponent.debug());
    });

    it('should log user into dashboard if correct credentials are provided', () => {
        const credentials = { username: 'joe', password: 'myspecialpassword' };

    });
});
```

I want to test a form submission, however I first need to enter in text into the `#input-auth-username` and the `#input-auth-password` input fields.

How do you do that with **[Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html)**?

Comment: you should probably convert the inputs to controlled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components. If you component state does not  control the value and change handlers of the input fields then enzyme can't directly make changes to them. The only way would be to do dom manipulation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Still waiting on a better answer, but thanks to this link https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76

Was able to accomplish text being entered into my form's inputs using the following code

```
it('input fields should be filled correctly', () => {
    const credentials = { username: 'leongaban', password: 'testpass' };
    expect(loginComponent.find('#input-auth-username').length).toBe(1);

    const usernameInput = loginComponent.find('#input-auth-username');
    usernameInput.value = credentials.username;
    expect(usernameInput.value).toBe('leongaban');

    const passwordInput = loginComponent.find('#input-auth-password');
    passwordInput.value = credentials.password;
    expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('testpass');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I think github issue link, your answer and question are a little unrelated as exposed here.